# fetching value of more tha one label on click event of a button using repeater

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying ASP Repeater control.

where i'm displaying the values from my Database using 3labels(which are inside repeater),

also i can fetch the value of one label on click event of a button(which is also inside repeater)

but,

i want to fetch the values of all 3 labels on click of same button

my aspx file is :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrHotel" runat="server" 
                                onitemcommand="rptrHotel_ItemCommand">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table width="500px"  class="bidTab">
                                        <tr class="bidHeading">
                                            <th>
                                                Hotel Name
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Room Type
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Bid
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblHotelName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("hotel_name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRoomType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("room_type_name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblBaseBidAmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("base_bid_ammount")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnBidNow" runat="server" Text="Bid Now" CommandName="BidNow" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("hotel_name") %>'/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </table>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

and the code i have tried in aspx.cs file is :

```
protected void rptrHotel_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "BidNow")
        {
            Label hotel_name = e.Item.FindControl("lblHotelName") as Label;
            hotel_name.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

            Label room_type_name = e.Item.FindControl("lblRoomType") as Label;
            room_type_name.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

            Label base_bid_ammount = e.Item.FindControl("lblBaseBidAmt") as Label;
            base_bid_ammount.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

            lblhotelresult.Text = lblhotelresult.Text;
            lblRoomResult.Text = room_type_name.Text;
            lblBaseamtresult.Text = base_bid_ammount.Text;

            //Session["hotel_name"] = hotel_name.Text;
            //Session["room_type_name"] = room_type_name.Text;
            //Session["base_bid_ammount"] = base_bid_ammount.Text;

            //Response.Redirect("BidRoomCustomer.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Please suggest what could be done and help me accessing all the 3labels.

Comment: So you have tried something, did it work? If not, what went wrong? One note: when are you databind the repeater? You should do that only `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: i can access only 1 label control from the above 3 controls ,

<asp:Button ID="btnBidNow" runat="server" Text="Bid Now" CommandName="BidNow" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("hotel_name") %>'/>

but i want to access all the 3 labels please suggest something.

Comment: Which label can you access? Do you get a `NullReferenceException` on the others? Why are you setting their `Text` property in `ItemCommand`? I assume you actually want to read their text to get the `base_bid_ammount` and `room_type_name`, don't you?

Comment: i can access lblHotelName. but as u said , i want to access the Text property of the Labels lblHotelName, lblRoomType and lblBaseBidAmt..

Comment: thankyou @TimSchmelter have got it by my self :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have done by my self.

need to handle multiple arguments.

changed my .aspx file to :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrHotel" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptrHotel_ItemCommand">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table width="500px" class="bidTab">
                                        <tr class="bidHeading">
                                            <th>
                                                Hotel Name
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Room Type
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Bid
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblHotelName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("hotel_name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRoomType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("room_type_name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblBaseBidAmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("base_bid_ammount")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnBidNow" runat="server" Text="Bid Now" CommandName="BidNow" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("hotel_name")+","+ Eval("room_type_name")+","+Eval("base_bid_ammount")%>'>
                                            </asp:Button>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </table>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

and my .aspx.cs file is :

```
protected void rptrHotel_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "BidNow" )
        {

            string[] arguments = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
            string hotel_name = arguments[0];
            string hotel_room_type = arguments[1];
            string base_bid_amt=arguments[2];

        }
```

this works fine :)